# How to divert traffic from a docker container's ethernet interface to a bridge?

Tags: linux, networking, docker

We have a virtualized solution in-place. I am trying to port the environment into docker. Now the problem I am facing is that like the way, docker uses the concept of network-namespace to create virtual ethernet interfaces and move the other end of my network-pipe to docker container, in the same way, virtualized environment running inside docker container is creating a bridge and clubbing all the virtual ethernet interfaces created for each virtualized host.

Now I am able to ping bridge IP created inside the docker. But ping is not going for the ip's created inside the network namespace for each virtual host.

This diagram will help in drawing the whole network stack:

**Host**:

```
bridge: docker0(172.17.0.1) ----> veth(some name given by docker)
```

**Container**:

```
eth3: 172.17.0.2(renamed purposely)

bridge:eth2(172.16.69.62) ---> eth0_host1 ----- eth1(host1:172.16.69.33)                                                             (                                              namepsace:net_host1)
                          ---> eth0_host2 ----- eth1(host2:172.16.69.34)
                                                namespace:net_host2)
```

Now, the problem is ping from the host machine to bridge: 172.16.69.62 is going on,
but it doesn't work if I try to ping to 172.16.69.33

Below are the routing tables for docker container:

```
0.0.0.0         172.17.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth3
172.16.69.32    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth2
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth3

For host:
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s8
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s8
```